# Binding function in QML

Tags: qt, qml

Is there a difference between

```
myProperty: myFunction()
```

or

```
myProperty: { ... }
```

or is the latter the same as the former?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are basically the same. In the latter version, any explicit return gives the property its value. If there is no return, the last expression in the block becomes the property value.

I prefer the first version when working exclusively with a JS expression and use the second form where the calculation takes some imperative logic. I always use explicit returns in the second form.

Comment: Cool, I am using it in the same scenarios as well, but I was wondering if there are any performance differences.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Should be equivalent.